# Is this advertisement allowed on a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I have seen this advert a few times this morning on the Stack Exchange network:

[image: Banner ad]

I think it is an artist's impression that mimics the likeness of Jackie Chan:

[image: Jackie Chan]

Is this allowed in an advertisement?

Comment: Not an official response, but, why would you think this is not allowed?

Comment: It's also a widely used image on sites like memebase

Comment: @Oded - I thought you needed permission to use someones likeness to promote a brand/product?

Comment: Not so much with celebrities, as far as I know (in particular for images that are in the public domain). It is also not clear to me how you know that codementor does not have permission.

Comment: Having said that, I am not a lawyer and not an expert on these matters.

Comment: My understanding is also that if this is an issue, it is up to the original photo copyright owner to chase up.

Comment: Possibly because as someone said, it is widely used on memes on the net. If codementor had permission, they would probably get a professional picture from a photoshoot, not a rehashed image.

Comment: Found this article on the topic: [Using the Name or Likeness of Another](http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/using-name-or-likeness-another). What I'm not sure about is what constitutes a 'likeness' - I don't know if it extends as far as drawn images of someone's face. However this is very unlikely to be a *copyright* problem, but it *might* be misappropriation of a person's likeness.

Comment: @Oded - yes, the original copyright owner should chase up, but that does not mean its morally or ethically ok to use copyright material as long as no one chases you up. Am I allowed to post copyright code on stackoverflow as long as the original author does not say anything?

Comment: And yet, this is not an ad made by Stack Exchange. Again, I am not an expert on any of this, and have brought it up to the attention of our ad team.

Comment: With respect to posting copyrighted code - SO technically can't *stop you* posting it, but can and will remove it if a valid DMCA takedown request comes in. If you don't have the right to post some code, you shouldn't post it.

Comment: @oded - exactly, its not made by StackExchange, but once alerted, do they not have an obligation to take it off?

Comment: I don't know. As I said, I am not an expert on these matters and have referred it to our ad team. Do you expect an immediate, irrevocable action, when things are not certain (even you don't seem to know for certain that this is an actual problem)?

Comment: @Husman: If you are referring to a DMCA takedown, then that should be issued by the copyright holder or an agent authorised to do so on their behalf. In this case, have you considered the possibility that the ad uses properly licensed material? Perhaps that image was used *with permission*? Neither Stack Exchange **nor you** can make that call, so you informing us that you find the use suspicious is never enough grounds.

Comment: @Oded - No, certainly not. I was not expecting immediate legal action and court cases or anything. I just wanted to point it out and appreciate your assistance and discussing the issue has helped clear up some things in my head regarding copyright.

Comment: @Husman: and in case that counts against me: I am listed on Codementor.io, but not under the jQuery tag. I could indirectly benefit from the advertisement (long shot). Just to disclose my affiliations. But so are many other people that have Stack Overflow accounts; listing yourself is free.

Comment: @MartijnPieters understood, me pointing it out is not enough grounds for removal, but does it not warrant investigation? That boils down to the same as saying 'you think this is copyright by apple/MS/google/(some other company) but the original authors have not said anything, so lets just use it anyway'

Comment: The specific image is in [widespread use as a meme signifying extreme confusion](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jackie%20chan%20meme)

Comment: @Husman: No, I don't think so; advertisements use popular images *all the time*; it'd be a full-time job to investigate all those. Instead, the responsibility lies with the copyright holders. As for celebrity likeliness, that ship has long sailed in the case of this image and as far as I can tell, depends on the context. Nowhere is there a claim that this is anything other than the 'confused' meme, not Jackie Chan the actor.

Comment: @Husman: If you have a problem with such an advert, why not *contact the copyright owners or agent of the celebrity*. I do feel you are raising a tempest in a teapot here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters IANAL, but the meme is used to promote a commercial organisation here. That might make it different from "normal" use of memes, legally speaking.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Perhaps, but that still doesn't make this an issue for Stack Exchange. That's what takedown notices are for. And it should be addressed to Codementor.io in any case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - that certainly was not the intention. I was not aware of the meme, and being a childhood JC fan, I just immediately saw the resemblance. Then it occurred to me that a martial arts/movie star endorsing jquery help on the internet seemed unlikely. So I bought up the question here on meta. If you feel it is perfectly ok to use it in this context, then let it be. I have never been involved in any copyright claims and do not know the process (I'm from the UK), so I thought it best to bring it to the attention of the site owners or community members.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll be glad to leave the details to SE's legal staff - again, IANAL, so I don't know if SE could get in trouble over this kind of thing (being "complicit" or "facilitating" or some such thing). As a user, I am curious what the position of SE's legal staff is, and would be interested if they have an answer.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, I do not think SE will get into trouble (or anyone for that matter, and at this rate. Besides I doubt Jackie Chan is checking adverts on SE). SE have no control over the exact adverts placed on their site, they just sign up to advertising network. If anything, I think the advert creator has more responsibility than the sites that the adverts are placed on. (I might be wrong though)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Sorry, might seem like a 'tempest in a teapot' again, but isn't that what community elders are for? To shoulder responsibility, instead of nudging it along to another department/person/company. Again, I apologise if this seems rude, but it seems very passive on your behalf. Its probably not even a big deal, but it would be nice to take some notice instead of the 'move along, its not my problem' attitude.

Comment: Folks, ***relax***, we've pinged the folks in our ad sales team to have a look. Let's give them a chance to do it. Comments here are starting to get a little derailed.

Comment: mfw Meta Stack Overflow is arguing about a meme based on a photo of Jackie Chan.

Comment: Note that I'm *not* suggesting that being a good sport about a meme and being ok with some version of it in an ad are the same, but FWIW, Mr. Chan seems to have a [solid sense of humor on this topic](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151946646137318&set=a.98876792317.90092.30382852317)

Answer (score 10):

This isn't the first time a [meme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme) based ad has appeared on our network. Remember this?

[image: Thank god that died]

Our ads team is *extremely* pedantic when it comes to the ads (even from customers) that get shown on the site. We want to show you stuff that's relevant and likely to be at least *somewhat* interesting, as much as possible. You wouldn't get that distinct impression from the sample I just linked, but I swear - they really do put a lot of attention into what we display.

I'm *sure* this particular ad was screened, however we have relayed your concerns to them, and they can chime in from here. I'm responding only because (1) comments are starting to get a little scary here and (2) this wouldn't fit in a comment anyway.

Relax, all, we're looking into it :)

Comment: Thank you for the update. The comments were getting derailed as it appeared that SE just wasn't bothered (at least to me), it just seemed like a case of, "yeah it might copyright but its not my problem, get someone else to deal with it", so thank you again.

Comment: Oded did indicate a few times that he relayed it to our ad team (who won't be in for another few hours), I picked up on this as he was making note of it in our internal chat. I'm sorry if you felt like it might have been brushed off, it truly wasn't.

Comment: I was aware that Oded had passed it on, but then the replies from MartijnPieters seemed like it was being brushed off, in particular this line: "still doesn't make this an issue for Stack Exchange". I just wasn't sure at that point anymore as to what was happening. Thanks again for clearing that up.

Comment: I for one am glad to hear SE is looking into it - I didn't expect otherwise. I'd still be interested to hear what their answer is. But if, for whatever reason, they decide it's better not to let us know, then I'm fine with that.

Comment: @Husman - Martijn has every right to expressing his opinion. He isn't a Stack Exchange employee, and has been chiming in as a community member. The people on Meta are community members just like you - there are a few staff members coming in as well - we normally have a diamond, whereas community members do not (except for our volunteer moderators). One way or another, staff members identify themselves as such on their profiles.

Comment: @Oded Except, of course, when we don't and volunteer moderators do. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear - I meant here on Meta Stack Exchange... though yes, that may change in the future.

Comment: @Oded We're on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AnnaLear - details, details. What am I, a programmer?

Comment: @Oded, I did not know about the diamond showing next to username. It was not clear to me, who is a community member and who is a mod.

Comment: If you hover over the diamond, you get a tooltip that says "moderator". Should be pretty obvious. You had to have wondered what the diamond meant… @husman

Comment: @CodyGray It could have been chinese text, emoji, smiley face or some other unicode character that my browser could not render. Hovering over weird characters is not the usual route a user takes, especially on a mobile device.

Comment: We need to bring this ad back